# How do you get location from background running javascript?

Tags: cordova, meteor, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have cordova javascript running in the background, triggered by phonegap pushPlugin background message processing (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/).

Calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't return the callback until the user resumes the app.

Is there any way to bypass this restriction?

Comment: on iOS or Android? iOS is very restrictive about what you are allowed to do in the background (not much!).

Comment: Both... But Android would be a good start